# Send dropdownlist value back to variable MVC 4

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi there I have a table of jobs with a specific id for them

```
id   title
1    Manager
2    Engineer
3    IT
```

I have created a way so that I am able to load these value from a database with this table and data.

Here is my model

```
[Display(Name = "Type: "),
Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> jobTitle { get; set; }
```

Here is my controller

```
public void loadDropDown()
        {
            JobModel selectedJob = new JobModel();
            reviewlogsEntities db = new reviewlogsEntities();

            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> type = db.types.Select(m => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)m.id),

                Text = m.title



            });


            ViewBag.JobTitle = type;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult DisplayJobTitle()
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {

                loadDropDown();

                return View();


            }       

            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DisplayJobTitle(JobModel curJob)
        {


            loadDropDown();

             if (ModelState.IsValid)
             {

                 return View();
             }

             else
             {

                 ModelState.AddModelError("", "Looks like there was an error                     with your job title, please make sure a job title is selected.");

             }

              return View();
        }
```

And Lastly what my view looks like:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please try again.")
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.type)
    @Html.DropDownList("JobTitle")

    <input class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Show Job Info" style="margin-left:126px;margin-bottom: 20px;" />
}
```

See the problem is that variable jobTitle in my model is null because I never give it a value and since I don't give it a value the form thinks it is not filled out since it must be required and will not submit properly. My question is how do I return the value of whatever the users selected as their job title back to jobTitle variable when the form is submitted so that I won't get a submission failure.

Answer (score 0):

Model should accept selected value not collection of items:

```
[Display(Name = "Type: "),
Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public int jobTitle { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a property to map selected value in your model like:

```
[Display(Name = "Type: "),
Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public int SelectedjobTitle { get; set; }
```

and then in your View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedJobTitle",ViewBag.JobTile as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the DropDownListFor like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JobTitle, Model.Jobs)
```

on your model:

```
[Display(Name = "Type: "),
Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public int JobTitle { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Jobs { get; set; }
```

don't forget to fill the "Jobs" on your controller.